# assertEqual error on nodeJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I just started nodejs development. I am testing mongodb driver but repeatedly getting assertEquals has no method.

code from [sourceRepo](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native)

```
var client = new Db('test', new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {})),
    test = function (err, collection) {
      collection.insert({a:2}, function(err, docs) {

        collection.count(function(err, count) {
          test.assertEquals(1, count);
        });

        // Locate all the entries using find
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
          test.assertEquals(1, results.length);
          test.assertTrue(results[0].a === 2);

          // Let's close the db
          client.close();
        });
      });
    };

client.open(function(err, p_client) {
  client.collection('test_insert', test);
});
```

Error

has no method 'assertEquals'

How to reolve it?

Comment: Do you have a testing framework? Writing an assertEquals function is easy though. Just return true if the two arguments are equal

Comment: oh no I didnt installed any testing framework

Comment: very new to development suggest me How to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Node's Assert](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) for this (where it is called equal rather than equal*s*):

```
var assert = require('assert');

// ...
assert.equal(count, 1);
// ...
```

However, for Unit tests or something similar you should consider using some testing framework. eg. [Jasmine for Node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node), which is very popular.

Answer (score 1):

`assert.equal` is **deprecated**: use `assert.strictEqual()` instead.

---

```
assert.equal(1, '1');
// OK, 1 == '1'

assert.strictEqual(1, '1');
// FAIL, 1 === '1'
```

Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_equal_actual_expected_message